# Why not a heat pump with only the outdoor air?

Tags: thermodynamics, fluid-dynamics, air

I was wondering why we can not use only the outside air for a heat pump? Taking the outside air, pass it through a compressor to increase pressure and temperature. Then the hot air flow heats the area, temperature decrease and finally, 2 has possible ways: aeration to avoid polluted air or to manage the flow rate, or recycle the air in the circuit.

Here is a sketch:

[image]

Could someone explain me?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Heat pumps that pump heat from the colder outside air into a home have been in commercial use for over 30 years. Just search for it. Another example is a refridgerator: it pumps heat from the cold sink into your kitchen,

Comment: your heat pump is very ineffective , so it would need very high pressure and still not heat enough . See the fluids and gases which are used in real heat pumps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The air conditioner process you describe (compress some air, shed the heat, expand the air back to low pressure and obtain cold air) is exactly what is used to air-condition airliners. The thermodynamic cycle used by these devices is called the *Coleman cycle*.

It's a lot less efficient than using a closed loop refrigerant that undergoes a liquid-gas phase change but it has very few parts, weighs much less than that refrigerant system, and is convenient where you have lots of compressed air available. In jet aircraft that compressed air is bled off the compressor stage of the engines.

Note that piston-powered planes have to use refrigerant systems instead because they do not generate gobs of compressed air as they run.

Answer (score 0):

If you compress air to heat it and then let the hot, dense air expand to its original volume in the warm region, all you have is a joule heater (the work done by the compressor is converted into heat) and a pump that moves cold air from the cold region into the warm region and vice versa. If you close the inflow and outflow vents on your diagram, you just have a very noisy and overpriced joule heater: one kWH of electricity gets you one kWH of heat. If you leave the inflow and outflow vents open (or just the inflow vent, all houses leak), you basically have an overpriced joule heater next to an open window.

A heat pump could use ambient air for a refrigerant gas, in which case it should compress it, pass it through a heat rejection coil in which the compressed air is kept compressed and allowed to radiate heat, and then pump the compressed air, which is now colder than it was when it started by $\Delta Q = \text{(radiated heat)} - \text{(work done by the compressor)}$, back into the cold region, preferably away from the intake.

A heat pump can also use a closed loop refrigerant, which is often better than air because a gas can be chosen that can efficiently exploit a change in phase. AFAIK this is much more common. A closed loop has a heat rejection coil and also a heat absorption coil, in which the refrigerant is re-heated to near the temperature of the cold region by exposure (through the coil) to the cold air.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However, why if I close the inflow and outflow vents, I have an overpriced joule heater (I have an idea, but I want to have yours)? Then, every time we have an open window, the heating efficiency decreases whatever the heating system, no?